# IDE expects semicolon after curly braces

Tags: java, parameters, interface

I have this code with parametrized Interfaces:

```
public enum CLIError implements IUIErrorEnum<CLIError>, IErrorEnum<CLIError> {
    @Override
    public ReaderType getType() {
        return ReaderType.CLI;
    }
```

Why does the IDE expect a ";" after the returning Type (ReaderType) of getType()?

The IDE placed a ";" after the opening bracket of the class:

```
public enum CLIError implements IUIErrorEnum<CLIError>, IErrorEnum<CLIError> {
;
    @Override
```

Why does the IDE (Eclipse in this case) generate the ";" after the Enum declaration and display a "expected ";" after the return type instead of a "missing members"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring an enum, not a class, so the compiler expects to see enum elements at the beginning. These elements should be separated by `,` and end with a `;`

```
public enum CLIError implements IUIErrorEnum<CLIError>, IErrorEnum<CLIError> {
    ELEMENT_1,
    ELEMENT_2,
    LAST_ELEMENT;

    @Override
    public ReaderType getType() {
        return ReaderType.CLI;
    }
}
```

Even if you don't declare any enum elements, the `;` is mandatory.

Note that if you don't declare a method in the enum, the `;` can be omitted.

```
public enum CLIError {
    // compiles without ;
}
```

or

```
public enum CLIError {
    ELEMENT_1,
    ELEMENT_2,
    LAST_ELEMENT
    // compiles without ;
}
```

Comment: But why would the Error be "expected ;" after the type? I know its an enum, I know the Error markup would disappear. But why this vague error? Why the autogenerated ";"

Comment: @gismo `;` is not expected after the type, but rather before the first method. This allows the compiler to distinguish between enum elements and methods.

Answer (score 1):

You defined an `enum`. In an `enum` you must define enum constants before you define any methods. If you don't define any constants, you must put a semi-colon there.

This is just how the syntax of enums is defined for Java, see [section 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) of the Java Language Specification.